# Django count guest user when visiting of index page

Tags: python, django, django-views

In Django
How to count guest user when visiting of index.html

My Django version is 1.8.2

Please help me?

---

Hi i do `pip install django-tracking` and then `migrate` it but i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/roshandel/vroshan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/roshandel/vroshan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/opt/roshandel/vroshan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/opt/roshandel/vroshan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/opt/roshandel/vroshan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/roshandel/vroshan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tracking/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.utils import HAS_GEOIP
ImportError: cannot import name HAS_GEOIP
```

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 2):

In fact there are different available [3rd party package](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/analytics/) to perform to provide website analytics.But since you only need visitor statistics the following can help you ; [django-tracking](https://github.com/bashu/django-tracking), [django-visitor](http://django-visitor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) and [django-statistics](https://github.com/attuch/django-statistics). But after checking the **django-statistics** reposiotry it seems like it's has the former packages as dependencies, which means it's a kind of wrapper for both, but as I see the last contribution is 3 years ago, while the last contribution in django-tracking is just 3 months ago. So I will recommend **django-tracking**.

```
 pip install django-tracking
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.sites',
        ...
        'tracking',
        ...
    )
```

**migration**

```
python manage.py migrate
```

For more configuration, check the [README](https://github.com/bashu/django-tracking)

Comment: @DhianTN does `django-tracking` work on `django 1.8.2`?
I give some errors when installing `django-tracking`

Comment: Based on the github [conversation](https://github.com/bashu/django-tracking/pull/23) it's should be compatible with django1.9, but not sure about 1.8 or earlier versions.

Comment: Yes in fact many changes have been applied in version 1.9, either check among the other [packages](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/analytics/) for a compatible one or you have to implement your own using a custom middelweare.